# Why greek strings does not shown in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, character

Why greek strings does not shown in MATLAB? I have this code
clc
clear

```
str1='Αθηνα'
a=double(str1)
```

the problem is that string characters in greek are not recognised. Also, in workspace are shown as ????

What I should do in order to fix it?

I use 2019a version

Comment: works for me in win 10 , matlab 2019b (copy pasted your code)

Comment: Also, works on MATLAB R2019b running on macOS Big Sur.

Comment: Does anybody knows where in prefferences could I change the default encoding to UTF-8 encoding?